# Type Mismatch during json parsing in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a json which is returning as a List. I am trying to parse it but I am getting an error named

_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'List'
Here is my code -

```
 List data = json.decode(response.body) as List; 
    var newsPageViewResult = data.map((i) => new NewsList.fromJson(i)).toList();
```

and my model class for the json

```
    class NewsList {
  final List<News> news;

  NewsList({
    this.news,
  });

  factory NewsList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {

    List<News> news = new List<News>();
    news = parsedJson.map((i)=>News.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return new NewsList(
        news: news
    );
  }
}

class News{
  final String status;
  final String type;

  News({
    this.status,
    this.type
  }) ;

  factory News.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return new News(

      status: json['status'],
      type: json['type'],
    );
  }}  

                                                                                                                                                                also this is how json is returning
```

[
  {
    "id": 10159,
    "date": "2018-07-23T11:34:22",
    "date_gmt": "2018-07-23T11:34:22",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http://the2is.com/?p=10159"
    },
    "modified": "2018-07-23T11:35:13",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-07-23T11:35:13",
    "slug": "only-25-rupees-will-be-removed-in-children-lack-of-blood",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",....]

I have explicitly declared what type of data is passed according to Dart 2.0 documentation and still error is there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, drop `var`, it only makes it less readable.
From what I can see, you are receiving a list of news as json, then you map it `List` and then you want to iterate through this list and create a list of `NewsLists`.

Instead, you should just create one `NewsList` object from the list, as you designed it :)

```
List data = json.decode(response.body) as List; 
NewsList newsPageViewResult = new NewsList.fromJson(data)
```